# what really benefit from use Event in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I found in Laravel have Events.
example, in their documentation, for log last login by user:

```
Event::listen('user.login', function($user)
{
    $user->last_login = new DateTime;
    $user->save();
});
```

but, without Events, i can make other function in AccountController and:

```
public function logLogin($user){
 $user->last_login = new DateTime;
    $user->save();
}
```

and call AccountController->logLogin from anywhere.

what really benefit from use Event in Laravel?

Comment: The code that triggers the Event does not need to know "*I need to call `AccountController::logLogin()` and five other functions now*", it doesn't even need to know that `AccountController` exists.

Comment: Events are regarded as callback functions. It do something when another thing is happened. If you know CakePHP for example, it is more flexible than beforeXXXX and afterXXXX callbacks in controllers and models.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Events are useful because you can fire one event and have multiple subscribers.

That means if user logs in and fires `user.login` event, you can perform multiple callbacks.

Now what that means is this: if you want to add functionality to your `AccountController::logLogin` method, you have to *alter* it.

With events, you can just stack multiple callbacks.

```
Event::listen('user.login', function($user)
{
    $user->last_login = new DateTime;
    $user->save();
});

Event::listen('user.login', function($user)
{
    // Do some other thing
});
```

Convenience lies in the fact you don't have to alter any method in order to add new functionality.